# Is there a way to get the exact time of password expiration (aside from the date)

Tags: debian, password

I can get the date with `chage -l username`, but I need to get the exact time. How can I get that?

Comment: There is no time associated to it. It will activate the 1st time someone tries to use an account on the day it expires.

Comment: I think the only question is if it's local time or UTC time that counts. The day probably starts at midnight anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, the details what you get from chage command that's far you get more details about the password details for a user.

```
[root@LinuxSYS ~]# chage -l linuxuser
Last password change                                    : Jun 19, 2019
Password expires                                        : Aug 18, 2019
Password inactive                                       : Sep 05, 11761240
Account expires                                         : Jan 20, 11761191
Minimum number of days between password change          : 1
Maximum number of days between password change          : 60
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 5
[root@LinuxSYS ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

The time will be `12:00:00 UTC` for the date the pasword expire, thus:

```
$ date -ud $(chage -l linuxuser | grep -P '^Password expires[[:space:]]*: ^K.*$')
Sun 18 Aug 2019 12:00:00 AM UTC
```

Or any other format that date could generate.